# Java, Getting text content with tags from DOM, in the same order the browser displays it

Tags: java, html, dom, web-scraping, jsoup

For my search engine i want to index HTML documents based on tags and their texts. This way i can e.g. inherit headlines to paragraphs.

For example I have given the following DOM:

```
  <body>
    <div1> one
      <h2> two </h2>
      <div2> three
        <div3> four </div3>
      </div2>
      <p> five </p> 
    six
    </div1>
    </body>
```

*What I want as output is:*

div1: one, 
h2 : two, 
div2: three, 
div3 : four, 
p: five, 
div1: six
(the same order the browser would display it)

However, with Jsoup I can only get either:

```
Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.parse(htmlExample);
Elements allTagsInOrderOfAppearance = htmlDocument.body().select("*");

//either 1.
for (Element element : allTagsInOrderOfAppearance){
       System.out.println(element.tagName() + ": " + element.ownText());
    }
```

*1. output:*
 'div1: one six, h2: two, div2: three, div3, four, p: five'

```
//or 2.
for (Element element : allTagsInOrderOfAppearance){
            if(element.parent().ownText().isEmpty()){
               System.out.println(element.tagName() + ": " + element.text());
            }
    }
```

*2. output:*
 'div1: one, two, three, four, five, six'

Is there another way to get my wished output with jsoup or with another libary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking over the Element nodes only. To get the output you want (where the `body` element's two text nodes are shown separately), you need to loop through the element's Text nodes, too. The easiest way to do this is with [`childNodes`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#childNodes--) with a recursive function. Along these lines *(conceptual, you'll probably have to tweak it)*:

```
public void visitNode(Node node) {
    if (node instanceof Element) {
        Element e = (Element)node;
        System.out.println(e.tagName());
        for (Node child : e.childNodes()) {
            this.visitNode(child);
        }
    } else if (node instanceof TextNode) {
        System.out.println(((TextNode)node).text());
    }
}
```

Then call it with the `body` element to kick things off.

That starts from a node and doesn't *quite* generate exactly the output you wanted. This version starts from a list of nodes and does:

```
static void visitNodes(List<Node> nodes, String prefix) {
    for (Node child : nodes) {
        if (child instanceof Element) {
            Element e = (Element)child;
            visitNodes(e.childNodes(), e.tagName() + ":");
        } else if (child instanceof TextNode) {
            if (prefix != null) {
                System.out.print(prefix);
            }
            System.out.println(((TextNode)child).text());
        }
    }
}
```

Complete working version:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String htmlExample = "<body>" +
            "<div1> one" +
              "<h2> two </h2>" +
              "<div2> three" +
                "<div3> four </div3>" +
              "</div2>" +
              "<p> five </p> " +
            "six" +
            "</div1>" +
            "</body>";
        Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.parse(htmlExample);
        visitNodes(htmlDocument.body().childNodes());
    }

    static void visitNodes(List<Node> nodes) {
        visitNodes(nodes, null);
    }
    static void visitNodes(List<Node> nodes, String prefix) {
        for (Node child : nodes) {
            if (child instanceof Element) {
                Element e = (Element)child;
                visitNodes(e.childNodes(), e.tagName() + ":");
            } else if (child instanceof TextNode) {
                if (prefix != null) {
                    System.out.print(prefix);
                }
                System.out.println(((TextNode)child).text());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked perfectly on the first try with my much more complex HTML. Saved me a lot of research.